# Javascript: Pushing an object to an array from a foreach

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I want to extract a collection of objects from an array based on their ID. I am using vanilla Javascript.

```
contacts = [
    {ID: 1, firstName: "Aaron", lastName: "Smith"},
    {ID: 2, firstName: "Ben", lastName: "Smith"},
    {ID: 3, firstName: "Conrad", lastName: "Smith"}
];
filteredContactIds = [1, 3];
filteredContacts = [];

filteredContactIds.forEach(function (filteredId) {
    filteredContacts.push(
        contacts.forEach(function (contact) {
            if (contact.ID == filteredId) {
                return contact;
            }
        })
    )
});
```

Contacts and filteredContactIds are simplified, in my code both arrays are both populated correctly. The problem is, the filteredContacts array is only receiving the ID property of each contact object, I want to insert the whole object.

I have exhausted my limited understanding. Can anyone point out the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that `Array#forEach` doesn't return a value. It just performs some operation(s) on each item in an array. This means `undefined` is being pushed to `filteredContacts`. You could use `contacts.filter` but you can remove the inner loop.

Using `Array#filter` and an array containment check:

```js
const contacts = [
    {ID: 1, firstName: "Aaron", lastName: "Smith"},
    {ID: 2, firstName: "Ben", lastName: "Smith"},
    {ID: 3, firstName: "Conrad", lastName: "Smith"}
];
const filteredContactIds = [1, 3];
const filteredContacts = contacts.filter(({ ID }) => filteredContactIds.includes(ID));
console.log(filteredContacts);
```

Instead of having to have two loops, one single run through the `contacts` array will work. This iterates through the array and checks whether the current contact's ID is inside the `filteredContactIds` array, removing another loop. Here's a desugared version for ES5 and below:

```js
var contacts = [
    {ID: 1, firstName: "Aaron", lastName: "Smith"},
    {ID: 2, firstName: "Ben", lastName: "Smith"},
    {ID: 3, firstName: "Conrad", lastName: "Smith"}
];
var filteredContactIds = [1, 3];
var filteredContacts = contacts.filter(function(contact) {
  return filteredContactIds.indexOf(contact.ID) > -1;
});
console.log(filteredContacts);
```

Instead of `Array#includes`, it uses `Array#indexOf`, and does not use object destructuring nor arrow functions nor `const`.

Comment: if es6 is available.

Comment: @NinaScholz Yep. I included a desugared version.

Comment: No arrow functions or `const` in es5

Comment: @charlietfl Done.

Comment: Solution <= ES5 worked like a charm, only thing I had to do was remove the close parenthesis after the -1.

Coming from a C# background, was confused by forEach taking a callable as a parameter, which is why I thought the callable needed to return the contact...

Comment: @BenE. Thanks for the catch! Functional JS can take a bit to get the hang of, but it's incredibly useful in situations like these. I recommend taking a look at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference). It's the most reliable and complete source for ES5 and beyond documentation.